# How to extract keys from multiple, nested arrays using jq

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jq

**SETUP**

I'm trying to figure out how jq filters work and having trouble figuring out nested arrays. Using the data below I cannot make a flat 5 key output. I can get 1 key and 4 nulls or 4 keys and 1 null, but not all 5 keys.

1 key, 4 nulls:

```
.Reservations[] | {OwnerId, InstanceId, ImageId, PrivateIpAddress, Platform}
```

Returns:

```
{
 "OwnerId": "000000000000",
 "InstanceId": null,
 "ImageId": null,
 "PrivateIpAddress": null,
 "Platform": null
}
```

4 keys, 1 null:

```
.Reservations[].Instances[] | {OwnerId, InstanceId, ImageId, PrivateIpAddress, Platform}

{
  "OwnerId": null,
  "InstanceId": "i-v33333333",
  "ImageId": "ami-44444444",
  "PrivateIpAddress": "10.0.0.0",
  "Platform": "windows"
}
```

For a various reasons I cannot use the "--query" option in AWS CLI which does return the format I'm looking for:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1 --profile temp --query 'Reservations[*].{InstanceId:Instances[0].InstanceId,IP:Instances[0].PrivateIpAddress,Platform:Instances[0].Platform,OwnerId:OwnerId}'
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "InstanceId": "i-11111111",
        "IP": "10.9.9.3",
        "OwnerId": "111111111111",
        "Platform": windows
    },
    {
        "InstanceId": "i-22222222",
        "IP": "10.0.0.0",
        "OwnerId": "111111111111",
        "Platform": windows
    }
]
```

Here is the JSON input:

```
   {
    "Reservations": [
        {
            "OwnerId": "000000000000",
            "ReservationId": "r-22222222",
            "Groups": [],
            "RequesterId": "111111111111",
            "Instances": [
                {
                    "Monitoring": {
                        "State": "enabled"
                    },
                    "PublicDnsName": null,
                    "State": {
                        "Code": 16,
                        "Name": "running"
                    },
                    "EbsOptimized": false,
                    "LaunchTime": "2015-04-10T00:02:02.000Z",
                    "Platform": "windows",
                    "PrivateIpAddress": "10.0.0.0",
                    "ProductCodes": [
                        {
                            "ProductCodeId": "0000000000000000000000000",
                            "ProductCodeType": "marketplace"
                        }
                    ],
                    "VpcId": "vpc-2222222",
                    "StateTransitionReason": null,
                    "InstanceId": "i-v33333333",
                    "ImageId": "ami-44444444",
                    "PrivateDnsName": "ip-10-0-0-0.aws.foobarcloud.com",
                    "KeyName": "bar-servicemesh",
                    "SecurityGroups": [
                        {
                            "GroupName": "bar-wildcard-dns-intranet-InstanceSecurityGroup-VN0DFQ13QCDY",
                            "GroupId": "sg-55555555"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ClientToken": "11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555_subnet-66666666_1",
                    "SubnetId": "subnet-66666666",
                    "InstanceType": "t2.medium",
                    "NetworkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "Status": "in-use",
                            "MacAddress": "00:00:00:00:00:77",
                            "SourceDestCheck": true,
                            "VpcId": "vpc-66666666",
                            "Description": null,
                            "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-11111111"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**QUESTION**
Using the JSON input above, how do you use jq to produce the following output?:

```
{
  "OwnerId": "000000000000",
  "InstanceId": "i-v33333333",
  "ImageId": "ami-44444444",
  "PrivateIpAddress": "10.0.0.0",
  "Platform": "windows"
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use a variable to store the `OwnerID` as in:

```
.Reservations[] | .OwnerId as $OwnerId | ( .Instances[] | { "OwnerId": $OwnerId, InstanceId, ImageId, PrivateIpAddress, Platform} )
```

Comment: Thanks Hans! This does get me over the hump. But I'd like some more color if anyone has any. Does this mean jq can't do this some other way?

Comment: You can get around using variables by building up the reservations like this: `{ OwnerId } + (.Instances[] | { InstanceId, ImageId, PrivateIpAddress, Platform })`

Comment: I believe that is a more elegant solution; perhaps you could provide it as an answer?

Comment: It wouldn't be that much different from your answer. You can take the snippet and integrate it into yours if you'd like. I don't understand Paul's follow up question so there's not much more I could add.

Comment: You added just the color I was looking for Jeff--Thanks!