# How to insert values of matching JSON Keys between 2 JSON files

Tags: javascript, json, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have 2 JSON files:

- A Template JSON
- A JSON output (from awscli)

The template is a small JSON file as below:

```js
{
  "DryRun": true,
  "ImageId": "",
  "KeyName": "",
  "SecurityGroups": [
    ""
  ],
  "InstanceType": "",
  "Monitoring": {
    "Enabled": false
  },
  "SubnetId": "",
  "DisableApiTermination": true,
  "PrivateIpAddress": "",
  "IamInstanceProfile": {
    "Arn": "",
    "Name": ""
  },
  "EbsOptimized": true,
  "TagSpecifications": [{
    "ResourceType": "",
    "Tags": [{
      "Key": "",
      "Value": ""
    }]
  }]
}
```

The original file is the output of `aws ec2 describe-instances`:

```js
{
  "Reservations": [{
    "OwnerId": "123456789012",
    "ReservationId": "r-12345678",
    "Groups": [],
    "Instances": [{
      "Monitoring": {
        "State": "disabled"
      },
      "PublicDnsName": "ec2-12-34-56-78.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com",
      "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
      "State": {
        "Code": 16,
        "Name": "running"
      },
      "EbsOptimized": false,
      "LaunchTime": "2016-02-09T03:06:21.000Z",
      "PublicIpAddress": "12.34.56.78",
      "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.1.2",
      "ProductCodes": [],
      "VpcId": "vpc-1a2b3c4d",
      "StateTransitionReason": "",
      "InstanceId": "i-abcd1234",
      "ImageId": "ami-1234abcd",
      "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-1-2.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal",
      "KeyName": "tempKey",
      "SecurityGroups": [{
          "GroupName": "somegroup1",
          "GroupId": "sg-ZZZZZ"
        },
        {
          "GroupName": "somegroup2",
          "GroupId": "sg-YYYYY"
        }
      ],
      "ClientToken": "NutKc123456789012",
      "SubnetId": "subnet-00001234",
      "InstanceType": "t2.medium",
      "NetworkInterfaces": [{
        "Status": "in-use",
        "MacAddress": "02:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE",
        "SourceDestCheck": true,
        "VpcId": "vpc-1a2b3c4d",
        "Description": "",
        "Association": {
          "PublicIp": "12.34.56.78",
          "PublicDnsName": "ec2-12-34-56-78.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com",
          "IpOwnerId": "123456789012"
        },
        "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-XXXXXXXX",
        "PrivateIpAddresses": [{
          "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-1-2.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal",
          "Association": {
            "PublicIp": "1.2.3.4",
            "PublicDnsName": "ec2-12-34-56-78.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com",
            "IpOwnerId": "123456789012"
          },
          "Primary": true,
          "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.1.2"
        }],
        "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-31-1-2.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal",
        "Attachment": {
          "Status": "attached",
          "DeviceIndex": 0,
          "DeleteOnTermination": true,
          "AttachmentId": "eni-attach-XXXXXXXX",
          "AttachTime": "2016-01-13T08:33:37.000Z"
        },
        "Groups": [{
            "GroupName": "somegroup1",
            "GroupId": "sg-ZZZZZZ"
          },
          {
            "GroupName": "somegroup2",
            "GroupId": "sg-YYYYYY"
          }
        ],
        "Ipv6Addresses": [],
        "SubnetId": "subnet-00001234",
        "OwnerId": "123456789012",
        "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.1.2"
      }],
      "SourceDestCheck": true,
      "Placement": {
        "Tenancy": "default",
        "GroupName": "",
        "AvailabilityZone": "ap-southeast-1b"
      },
      "Hypervisor": "xen",
      "BlockDeviceMappings": [{
        "DeviceName": "/dev/xvda",
        "Ebs": {
          "Status": "attached",
          "DeleteOnTermination": true,
          "VolumeId": "vol-33221100",
          "AttachTime": "2016-01-13T08:33:39.000Z"
        }
      }],
      "Architecture": "x86_64",
      "StateReason": {
        "Message": "Client.UserInitiatedShutdown: User initiated shutdown",
        "Code": "Client.UserInitiatedShutdown"
      },
      "RootDeviceName": "/dev/xvda",
      "VirtualizationType": "hvm",
      "Tags": [{
          "Value": "SomeValue",
          "Key": "SomeKey"
        },
        {
          "Value": "AnotherValue",
          "Key": "Name"
        }
      ],
      "AmiLaunchIndex": 0
    }]
  }]
}
```

I want to copy the values of the Keys in the original JSON file to the template file.

For example, `KeyName` is a common key between the 2 JSON files. The corresponding value `tempKey` is replaced in the template file.

The main use case of this is: I am trying to migrate a number of servers on AWS from 1 region to another. This is a part of migration process which will remove tons of manual clicking and configuration on AWS Console.

Note: I use BASH command line.

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to do this with [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) but it doesn't take a JSON template as input.

You'll have to modify it to become a query. This isn't the actual query you need, but something to get you started:

```
cat temp.json | jq '.Reservations[].Instances[] |  { DryRun, ImageId, KeyName, SecurityGroups, InstanceType, Monitoring }'
```

Where `temp.json` is your output above that I placed into a file. For regular commands, just do something like `aws ec2 describe-instances | jq ...`

The output that gives me (keep in mind the restricted set I queried for) is:

```
{
  "DryRun": null,
  "ImageId": "ami-1234abcd",
  "KeyName": "tempKey",
  "SecurityGroups": [
    {
      "GroupName": "somegroup1",
      "GroupId": "sg-ZZZZZ"
    },
    {
      "GroupName": "somegroup2",
      "GroupId": "sg-YYYYY"
    }
  ],
  "InstanceType": "t2.medium",
  "Monitoring": {
    "State": "disabled"
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, I found this that has some more recipes for working with `describe-instances` output and `jq`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30601278/how-to-extract-keys-from-multiple-nested-arrays-using-jq